# Combine several rules into one redirect Apache .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have two rules in my .htaccess file, first one is redirecting http to https, and the second one is making a url clean.

Is it possible to combine them somehow to get less redirects to an end user?

```
// http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://examplename.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

// clean url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this combine rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ https://examplename.com/$1 [L,NE,R=301]
```